# macro to redefine section for accessibility tagging doesn't work with \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, luatex, tagpdf

I wrote a macro to tag section headings using the `tagpdf` package. It works unless I have a `\tableofcontents` directive. In that case, any starred sections, such as the contents section itself, are replaced in the Table of Contents with an asterisk. I wonder if a more experienced LaTeX macro writer can tell me what I did wrong in my macro. Following is a minimum reproducible example. It must be run with a recent version of lualatex to work at all.

```latex
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=tagpdf,activate=tagging,uncompress}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsection}{\section}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \@ifstar{%
    \tagpdfparaOff\tagstructbegin{tag=H1}\tagmcbegin{tag=H1}%
    \oldsection*{#1}\tagmcend\tagstructend\tagpdfparaOn%
  }{%
    \tagpdfparaOff\tagstructbegin{tag=H1}\tagmcbegin{tag=H1}%
    \oldsection{#1}\tagmcend\tagstructend\tagpdfparaOn%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{bla}
bla bla bla

\section{bla bla}
bla bla bla

\subsection{bla bla bla}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving \section one argument, and if you then use `\section*` the star is this argument. Your `\@ifstar` isn't doing anything useful. Something like this will work for lualatex (with pdflatex this isn't a good way as the tagging can affect spacing and page breaking).

But this is only a temporary solution until the sectioning commands have been adapted to offer proper hooks.

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{testphase=tagpdf,activate=tagging,uncompress}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\NewCommandCopy\oldsection\section

\RenewDocumentCommand\section{som}
 {%
   \par%ensure that you are in vmode
   \tagpdfparaOff\tagstructbegin{tag=H1}\tagmcbegin{tag=H1}%
   \IfBooleanTF {#1}%test the star
   {%
    \IfValueTF{#2}% test the optional argument
     {\oldsection*[#2]{#3}}
     {\oldsection*{#3}}%
   }  
   {%
    \IfValueTF{#2}% test the optional argument
     {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}
     {\oldsection{#3}}%
   }%
  \tagmcend\tagstructend\tagpdfparaOn 
}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{bla}
bla bla bla

\section{bla bla}
bla bla bla

\subsection{bla bla bla}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I only need a temporary  answer at this point.  I can change when the sectioning commands change.